# Different font for specific heading

Tags: fonts, sectioning, titlesec

I use the `titlesec` package to define my design of the headings, in the following way.

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}
  {\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

Is it possible to change the format for one specific case? Lets say have a completely different format for chapter 1.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Yes: add  the \titleformat command you want just before chapter 1, and put the whole thing in a groups to make it local.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: And what about the table of contents? Do you wish a different entry there as well?

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
\begingroup
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
   {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
   {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{5pt}{\Huge}
   \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{10pt}
\chapter{chapter 1}
\endgroup
```